# Drawing Line is flickering in SDL2 C++. How To Modify My Game Loop?

Tags: c++, drawing, rendering, sdl-2

My line drawing works fine, but the line is flickering.
I was thinking to change the FPS of my loop, but I think I only have to add my RenderPresent() code in another line or add some new code for rendering the line. I tried a lot of possibilities and nothing worked.

What can I do to stop the line flickering?
If you need more information please write a comment.

```
// Global variables
SDL_Event event;             // Event object
int mouse_x = 0;             // Actual Mouse Coordinate X
int mouse_y = 0;             // Actual Mouse Coordinate Y
int mouse_last_x = 0;        // The coordinate X by last click
int mouse_last_y = 0;        // The coordinate Y by last click
bool dragged = false;        // Boolean after I clicked on some place
bool running = true;         // Makes the game loop run

void GameWin::loop()         //Game Loop
{
    while (running)
    {
        SDL_GetMouseState(&mouse_x, &mouse_y);  // Get Mouse Coordninates
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(GameWin::renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);  // Draw The Background Black

        update();
        render();  

        switch (event.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            running = false;
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  // Mouse Click Event
            if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
            {
                mouse_last_x = mouse_x; // After Left Click Save my Mouse Coordingates
                mouse_last_y = mouse_y;
                dragged = true;        
            }
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            if (dragged)
            {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(GameWin::renderer, 137, 255, 85, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE); // Set The Color Line To Green
                SDL_RenderDrawLine(GameWin::renderer, mouse_last_x, mouse_last_y, mouse_x, mouse_y); // Draw The Line
                SDL_RenderPresent(GameWin::renderer); // Render Line
            }
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if (dragged)
            {
                dragged= false;
                mouse_last_x = mouse_x;
                mouse_last_y = mouse_y;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

// My render method 
void GameWin::render()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(GameWin::renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(GameWin::renderer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't check if any event happened at all. You call `SDL_PollEvent`, and then process event - it might be ok, or it might be completely wrong as there is no guarantee there was an event in queue. `SDL_PollEvent` returns 0 if queue is empty - which means it didn't fill your event structure with meaningful data.

Second, don't combine event handling with drawing. Fetch all events that happened between iterations, then draw once.

Basically it should be something like:

```
#include "SDL.h"

// Global variables
SDL_Event event;             // Event object
int mouse_x = 0;             // Actual Mouse Coordinate X
int mouse_y = 0;             // Actual Mouse Coordinate Y
int mouse_last_x = 0;        // The coordinate X by last click
int mouse_last_y = 0;        // The coordinate Y by last click
bool dragged = false;        // Boolean after I clicked on some place
bool running = true;         // Makes the game loop run

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *w = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(640, 480, 0, &w, &renderer);

    while (running)
    {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_GetMouseState(&mouse_x, &mouse_y);  // Get Mouse Coordninates
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                running = false;
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  // Mouse Click Event
                if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                {
                    mouse_last_x = mouse_x; // After Left Click Save my Mouse Coordingates
                    mouse_last_y = mouse_y;
                    dragged = true;        
                }
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if (dragged)
                {
                    dragged= false;
                    mouse_last_x = mouse_x;
                    mouse_last_y = mouse_y;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!running) break;

        if (dragged)
        {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 137, 255, 85, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE); // Set The Color Line To Green
            SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, mouse_last_x, mouse_last_y, mouse_x, mouse_y); // Draw The Line
        }

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
}
```